# Selecting markers (bullets, numbering etc) of a specific list using CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, markers

I have the following code<sup>1</sup> in which the `::marker` psudeo-element is used to style the markers of the lists (i.e. bullets and numbering). However, it selects the markers of all the lists that are used in the html document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
::marker { 
  color: blue;
  font-size: 23px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

I only want to style the markers of the unordered list `<ul>`, so I changed the CSS code of the pseudo-element to:

```
ul::marker { 
color: blue;
font-size: 23px;
}
```

But when I run this code, the style doesn't apply to any list and gives me a simple output without any styles. How do I fix this?

---

<sup>1. The code has been taken from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_marker)</sup>

Comment: Use ul li::marker

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to apply the marker pseudo-element to the li element.

So the code could be like this:

```
ul li::marker { 
  color: blue;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `ul li::marker`?
Because having just `ul::marker` doesn't really specify for which list you are tryin to apply that style.
The style class would look like this:

```
<style>
ul li::marker { 
  color: blue;
  font-size: 23px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ul li::marker` instead of `ul::marker`.

Markers are for the `li` elements, not for the `ul` itself.

This would be your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul li::marker { 
  color: blue;
  font-size: 23px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```